# algorithm to add values of two ranges and place them into a third one

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, stl

I was just wondering if there was anything (either in c++11 or boost) that could help me do something like this:

```
std::vector<int> v1 = {1, 2, 3};
std::vector<int> v2 = {2, 5, 4};
std::list<int> res;
algorithm(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end(), back_inserter(res), std::plus<int>());
```

the result should of course be {3, 7, 7} and where instead of std::plus could be any binary_function.

So if anyone has an idea, let me know.

Comment: [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the 5 parameter overload of [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) for this. This takes a binary functor to operate on pairs of elements of two ranges:

```
std::transform(v1.begin(), 
               v1.end(), 
               v2.begin(), 
               back_inserter(res), 
               std::plus<int>());
```

Comment: oh ok I didn't know there was a version with five parameters. I should have looked better, thanks a lot all.

Comment: +1 for resisting the temptation to use a lambda when there's already a std functor for it.

Answer (score 12):

Just for fun, I'll point to an alternative to `std::vector` and `std::transform`. You could use `std::valarray` instead.

```
#include <valarray>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::valarray<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
    std::valarray<int> b = {2, 5, 4};

    std::valarray<int> c = a + b;    // look ma, no transform!

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
        std::cout << c[i] << "\t";
}
```

Result:

```
3       7       7
```

Unfortunately, even though the code for adding the valarrays together is simple and clean, valarray has never gained much popularity. As such, we're left with this rather strange situation where even code like that above that strikes me as very clean, straightforward and readable still almost qualifies as obfuscated, simply because so few people are accustomed to it.

Comment: +1 ah really cool, I didn't know that it was a vectorized array. I take it it also works with all the other arithmetic operators.

Comment: ah, didn't know that existed either, could come in handy someday.

Comment: @TemplateRex: Yeah, pretty much all of them. You can also do things like `valarray + int` to add a number to each member of the valarray (e.g., in the example, above, `c + 1` would give `4 8 8`).

Answer (score 4):

[std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

std::transform (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is what you might be looking for.