# Initializing a vector<char> using string literals

Tags: c++, c++11

What's correct behavior for following code ?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
  std::vector<char> v = { "y", "z" };  
  std::cout << v[0];

  return 0;
}
```

This is accepted by [*`Clang`*](http://rextester.com/EKJM68892) but not by [*`GCC`*](http://rextester.com/ZCPSM72798) and [*`VC++`*](http://rextester.com/KMRN72944)

Is this not an undefined behavior ?

Comment: It's undefined behaviour. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112281/c11-initializer-list-fails-but-only-on-lists-of-length-2

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: AHA! I finally found it! http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/129

Comment: What is the point of using vector<char> with a single string literal? Can't you use a char literal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After digging a bit into standards, I found following :

Here, I am trying to initialize `vector<char>`  using two string literals, not two chars.
using `vector(initializer_list<T>)`. In this case, `vector(initializer_list<char>)`.

But the type of a string literal is *"array of n const char"*, so the initializer-list constructor is not a match.

This *doesn't* result in compiler error, since the compiler is able to find another constructor that *matches*

§13.3.1.7¶1 explains the rules :

> "When objects of
>   non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized, overload resolution
>   selects the constructor in two phases:
>
> — Initially, the candidate
>   functions are the initializer-list constructors of the class T and the
>   argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument
>   [which we have seen didn't match].
>
> — If no viable initializer-list
>   constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where
>   the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and
>   the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list."

And the match in this case is :

```
template <class InputIterator> vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
```

The type of `InputIterator` has no info of `T` in the `vector<T>`. 
So even if I'm initializing a `vector<char>`, the two arguments can be of arbitrary type. 
The only requirement is that they stick to `InputIterator` property, which `const char[]` happens to do.

The constructor believes it has been passed two iterators to the same sequence, 
but it has actually been passed iterators to two completely different sequences, `"y"` and `"z"`.

So the result of this program is ***undefined*** .

<sup>*Thanks to chris's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837275/initializing-a-vectorchar-using-string-literals/26837580#comment42240394_26837275) 
This is post is exactly same as he mentioned over there. See [this](http://cppquiz.org/quiz/question/129?result=UD&answer=&did_answer=Answer)*</sup>