# What is the difference between these two forms of list initialization for std::map?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, list-initialization

I have tested the following two forms with clang and they are both accepted:

```
using IntMap = std::map<int, int>;

IntMap map1 {{
  {1, 1},
  {2, 2},
  {3, 3},
  {4, 4}
}};

IntMap map2 {
  {1, 1},
  {2, 2},
  {3, 3},
  {4, 4}
};
```

On Visual Studio 2013, the latter example fails to compile stating there is no constructor in map that takes 4 arguments.

I'm assuming both are actually valid. What is the difference between the two? Why doesn't the second example work on Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Both are legal. The first style may occasionally cause [weird things to happen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112281/c11-initializer-list-fails-but-only-on-lists-of-length-2/24112395#24112395). If the second doesn't work on VS2013 it's a compiler bug.

Comment: @T.C. Great read; thanks for the link. Unfortunately I think I need to "risk" it here since I need this code working on MSVC *and* Clang (unless you can suggest a reasonable alternative). If you post an answer with this I would be more than happy to give you a green checkmark!

Comment: @T.C.Could you please post your comment as an answer to my question? If you do, I'll mark yours as the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As T.C. pointed out in comments, both are legal. The first style [can cause weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112281/c11-initializer-list-fails-but-only-on-lists-of-length-2/24112395#24112395), but if the second fails for you in VS2013 then that's a compiler bug )or partial implementation).