# unordered_set construction ambiguity

Tags: c++, c++11

When I construct an unordered_set using an initialize list of three or more items, my compiler (Solstudio 12.4) compiles without complaint:

```
unordered_set<string> sam({"a", "b", "c"});
```

However, if I reduce the number of items in the initializer list to exactly 2, the compiler complains

```
unordered_set<string> bob({"a", "b"});
```

> Error: Overloading ambiguity between
>
> "std::unordered_set, 
>                      std::equal_to, 
>                      std::allocator>::unordered_set(
>                          std::initializer_list, 
>                          unsigned long, const std::hash&, const std::equal_to&, const
>   std::allocator&)" and
>
> "std::unordered_set, std::equal_to,
>   std::allocator>::unordered_set(
>                          std::unordered_set, std::equal_to,
>   std::allocator>&&)". 1 Error(s) detected.

I'm pretty sure I can cast this error away but I'm curious about why the compiler chokes for this case. Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24112395/4342498

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your compiler has bug, since when you construct from `initializer_list` constructor, that receives `initializer_list` should be preffered.

In your case second constructor is copy constructor, so, looks like compiler have two variants:

```
unordered_set<string> bob(unordered_set<string>{"a", "b"})
```

and

```
unordered_set<string> bob({"a", "b"});
```

Thanks to **0x499602D2**, for explanation, actually `unordered_set` has constructor, that takes two iterators and in your case compiler takes it, that is incorrect, since `initializer_list` constructor should be preffered.
You can try to use following:

```
unordered_set<string> bob{"a", "b"};
```

Comment: Seems that way. Very bizarre though, why would a init list of one item work and N items work, but not two?

Comment: @MustafaOzturk have no idea, but you can just look at unordered_set header and looks at constructors of unordered_set.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk `std::unordered_set` has a constructor that takes iterators (two arguments deduced by templates). Your strings can act as iterators as they can be converted to pointers. Your compiler is incorrectly choosing that overload.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'm not providing it two arguments though, I'm providing the constructor one argument (the initializer list) which in turn has two elements.  Logged a question to oracle.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk The braces can construct a temporary `unordered_set` and then the initializer clauses `"a"` and `"b"` are the arguments to its constructor. That's why you have an ambiguity between the copy-constructor and the one taking an initializer list.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. That explains it.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Am I misunderstanding the link from @NathanOliver? It seems to be explaining that it's not a compiler bug: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24112395/4342498

Comment: @PeterSW I'm not sure if it's a bug either, but it's not unsurprising behavior to me.