# Yet another counterintuitive behaviour of vector's constructor

Tags: c++, vector, overloading, language-lawyer

I hope you find this question and the answer instructional/educational (at least some of you).
First, lets try to guess the output of this program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  vector<char> delimiters = { ",", ";" };  
  cout << delimiters[0];
}
```

Try to answer 2 questions:

1. Is this program well-formed?
2. What is the output of this program?

Comment: Similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24112281/c11-initializer-list-fails-but-only-on-lists-of-length-2

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I'd like to make some suggestions for how to phrase it. The title would be a nice intro to a blog post, but it's not very searchable. It should describe the issue more specifically. Also, asking the question in a quiz-style is not ideal (even for a self-answered question). While there's no need for additional research, as the question is clear, the second part of your question is trivially answerable, so you should *at least* state what the output the program produces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as some of you may think (this is what I thought at the first place), this should lead to a compilation error, hence we are passing string literals instead of chars to the constructor, right?
Wrong!

Here we are trying to initialize a vector using two string literals, not two chars.

The `initializer-list` constructor for `template <class T>vector` is defined as `vector(initializer_list<T>)` by [[vector.overview]§26.3.11.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/vector.overview) in the standard. In our case, `vector(initializer_list<char>)`.
The type of a string literal is "array of n `const char`" [([lex.string]§5.13.5¶8)](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.string#8), so clearly the initializer-list constructor is not a match.
This problem does however not result in a compiler error, since the compiler is able to find another constructor that matches!

[[over.match.list]§16.3.1.7¶1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.match.list#1) explains the rules very clearly:
"When objects of non-aggregate class type T are list-initialized (...), overload resolution selects the constructor in two phases:
— Initially, the candidate functions are the `initializer-list constructors` of the class T and the argument list consists of the initializer list as a single argument [which we have seen didn't match].
— If no viable initializer-list constructor is found, overload resolution is performed again, where the candidate functions are all the constructors of the class T and the argument list consists of the elements of the initializer list [in our case, the two string literals "," and ";" ]".

Going back to [[vector.overview]§26.3.11.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/vector.overview), we find this candidate:

```
template <class InputIterator> vector(InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
```

Note that the type of InputIterator has no link to the type of T in the vector. So even if we are initializing a vector, the two arguments can be of arbitrary type. The only requirement is that they confirm to the concept of InputIterator, which const char[] happens to do.

Now the constructor believes it has been passed two iterators to the same sequence, but it has actually been passed iterators to two completely different sequences, "," and ";". [[forward.iterators]§27.2.5¶](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/forward.iterators#2) says: "The domain of == for forward iterators is that of iterators over the same underlying sequence.". So the result of this program is undefined.

So the aswer to our questions is:

1. The program is ill-formed.
2. The output of the program is underfined.